ubuntu studio 24.04 shortcuts on toolbar upper left corner of the screen are missing after upgrade

ubuntu studio 24.04 program shortcuts on toolbar upper left corner of the screen missing, darktable, gimp, etc. i had this problem when i upgraded to 22.04. I found an easy solution but I don't remember and am having trouble finding it for my 24.04 upgrade

This question is similar to: Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please post a screenshot

i don't know how to post a screenshot

file:///home/george/Pictures/Screenshot_20240920_181039.png

i think i added a screenshot

Open a terminal and enter the following commands
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install ubuntustudio-desktop^

That should restore the missing programs as well as the default icon theme.

it did not. I still have a question mark file icons, This happened to my 22.04 LTS upgrade, and there was a fix, but I can't remember what it was. it was something in terminal.

the programs don't seem to be missing. just the icons.

when i click on them i get a plasma desktop workspace error box that says unknown application folder. installed gimp through the software package manager and an icon appeared. this is very weird
